# How to load high resolution image

Tags: android, resolution

I hava a high resolution(1188 * 17617 2.35MB) image and I want to load it in my Android APP.
If I use WebView, the image can display. But it is indistinct. I open it with browser in Android OS, it also indistinct.
If I use ImageView, it just display nothing.

Comment: Scaled down your image that's the only one solution......

Answer (score 1):

You can scale down your bitmaps before loading them into the memory if they are too large. You can accomplish that by using `BitmapFactory.Options` and scale down as per your requirement.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth,
                int reqHeight) {

       final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

       options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        return bmp;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
             int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                    inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            }
        }
     return inSampleSize;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Picasso library. http://square.github.io/picasso/.

It deals with everything for you including downloading, caching and most importantly for you downsampling via a resize function. It also works with a standard ImageView with very little code:

Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)